# Difference in output order in Debug and Run modes in Eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

Why is the representation of the output of the following Java program differs in Debug and in Run as Java application modes in Eclipse?

For the below Java code,

```
public class ThrowDemo {

    static void demoproc() {
        try {
            NullPointerException nullPointerException = new NullPointerException();
            throw nullPointerException; // or new NullPointerException();
            //System.out.println("Unreachable Code is an error in Java");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught inside demoproc.");
            throw e; // rethrow the exception
        }
    }

    static void throwing(){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            demoproc();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Recaught: " + e);
        }
        throwing();
    }
}
```

the output must be in this order of listing which I get, when I debug it as Java application.

```
Caught inside demoproc.
Recaught: java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at throwkeyword.ThrowDemo.throwing(ThrowDemo.java:17)
    at throwkeyword.ThrowDemo.main(ThrowDemo.java:26)
```

When i run it as Java application, the listing is as follows :

```
Caught inside demoproc.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at throwkeyword.ThrowDemo.throwing(ThrowDemo.java:17)
    at throwkeyword.ThrowDemo.main(ThrowDemo.java:26)
Recaught: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Why it(the console) gives such a difference in Eclipse?

Comment: `System.out` vs `System.err`